# How write this complex query in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I use mysql and try to write this query into a model of Codeigniter. This query run perfectly in phpmyAdmin.

```
SELECT 
        a.ar, 
        a.jabatan, 
        COUNT(*) AS JumlahWPBaru, 
        SUM( 
            CASE WHEN a.no_shim IS NOT NULL 
            THEN 1 
            WHEN a.no_shim IS NULL 
            THEN 0 
            END ) AS JumlahHimbauan
        FROM (

        SELECT 
            a.ar, 
            c.jabatan, 
            a.npwp, 
            a.kpp, 
            a.cab, 
            a.namawp, 
            b.kd_shim, 
            b.no_shim, 
            b.tgl_shim
        FROM mfwpbudi a
        LEFT JOIN tb_shimbauan b ON ( a.npwp = b.npwp ) 
        LEFT JOIN easystp_user c ON ( SUBSTR( a.ar, 1, 9 ) = c.id_user ) 
        WHERE a.tanggal_daftar >  '2013-12-31'
        AND c.jabatan =  '05E'
        ) AS a
        GROUP BY a.ar
```

Here the model that I write.

```
function m_data_penyampaian_shim()
{
    $this->db->query("SELECT 
        a.ar, 
        a.jabatan, 
        COUNT(*) AS JumlahWPBaru, 
        SUM( 
            CASE WHEN a.no_shim IS NOT NULL 
            THEN 1 
            WHEN a.no_shim IS NULL 
            THEN 0 
            END ) AS JumlahHimbauan
        FROM (

        SELECT 
            a.ar, 
            c.jabatan, 
            a.npwp, 
            a.kpp, 
            a.cab, 
            a.namawp, 
            b.kd_shim, 
            b.no_shim, 
            b.tgl_shim
        FROM mfwpbudi a
        LEFT JOIN tb_shimbauan b ON ( a.npwp = b.npwp ) 
        LEFT JOIN easystp_user c ON ( SUBSTR( a.ar, 1, 9 ) = c.id_user ) 
        WHERE a.tanggal_daftar >  '2013-12-31'
        AND c.jabatan =  '05E'
        ) AS a
        GROUP BY a.ar");
    $qry=$this->db->get();
    return $qry->result();
}
```

but I get the error :

> Error Number: 1096
>
> No tables used
>
> SELECT *
>
> Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\himbauanwpbaru\system\database\DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 330

How I solve this problem ? Are there something I left from the code above?
I appreciate any suggestion and solutions.
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$this->db->query()` function ONLY returns TRUE/FALSE on success or failure. It DOES NOT return a database result set, nor does it set the query timer, or compile bind data, or store your query for debugging. It simply lets you submit a query. Most users will rarely use this function.

Try this way:-

```
$sql  = "SELECT 
        a.ar, 
        a.jabatan, 
        COUNT(*) AS JumlahWPBaru, 
        SUM( 
            CASE WHEN a.no_shim IS NOT NULL 
            THEN 1 
            WHEN a.no_shim IS NULL 
            THEN 0 
            END ) AS JumlahHimbauan
        FROM (

        SELECT 
            a.ar, 
            c.jabatan, 
            a.npwp, 
            a.kpp, 
            a.cab, 
            a.namawp, 
            b.kd_shim, 
            b.no_shim, 
            b.tgl_shim
        FROM mfwpbudi a
        LEFT JOIN tb_shimbauan b ON ( a.npwp = b.npwp ) 
        LEFT JOIN easystp_user c ON ( SUBSTR( a.ar, 1, 9 ) = c.id_user ) 
        WHERE a.tanggal_daftar >  '2013-12-31'
        AND c.jabatan =  '05E'
        ) AS a
        GROUP BY a.ar";

$query = $this->db->query($sql);
$result = $query->result_array();
return $result;
```

Comment: @mas_budhi: If it is working fine then tick it as accepted. :)