# Does codeigniter $this->db->query() or $this->db->escape() prevent SQL Injection?

Tags: php, codeigniter, security

I want to ask about these 2 method `$this->db->escape()` and `$this->db->query()`

Do those can prevent SQL Injection?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you should have clear idea of what is **[`db->escape()`](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html#escaping-queries)** and **[`db->query()`](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html#simplified-queries)** does.

---

### `db->escape()`

This used for users who use **[Regular Queries](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html#regular-queries)** rather **[Query Builder Class](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#query-builder-class)**. When we use a direct query to DB, there is a high vulnerability to security. So CI made `escape()` from those attacks. And ***[there are 3 methods we can use](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html#escaping-queries)*** and **`escape()` is one of them**.

### `db->query()`

This method was added to **[version 1.5.0](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/changelog.html?highlight=simple_query()#version-1-5-0)** and it's still there in CI database class with major+minor improvements in v1.5 - V3.0( v4 too). This use to execute **[complex queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34851466/how-write-this-complex-query-in-codeigniter)** and **[SP](https://www.eknowledgetree.com/codeigniter/easy-steps-to-call-stored-procedure-in-codeigniter/)** in an easy way with better understanding. This method **[just run a query whatever inside this `query()`](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html#simplified-queries)** and it has ***no any SQL injection preventation***.

---

### `escape()` can use separately?

No. In order to use these **[Escaping methods](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html#escaping-queries)** in CI, you have to use `query()`. `escape()`, `escape_str()` and `escape_like_str()` were added to SQL queries and obviously they need `query()` to perform any sort of action.

---

### Do those can prevent SQL Injection?

Yes of course. They're there to help with security. And read **[Input Security Filtering `post('some_data', TRUE);`](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/input.html#input-filtering)  and [Security](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/security.html#security) for better understanding.**

Answer (score 2):

By default `query()` **does not have any injection prevention methods unless you are using binds.**

```
$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE column1 = '?'", array($this->input->post('someitem')));
```

However, if you use query builder: `get()`, `insert()`, and `update()` as well any of the other **query builder** methods pass the incoming data through a function that among other things, **escapes the data.**

At face value, **escaping the data is part of preventing SQL injection**, and the other part is prepared queries (which with traditional php is accomplished using PDO and prepared statements). As query builder carries most of the load for you I wouldn't worry about that too much.

In CI you are safe doing:

```
$item = $this->input->post('someitem');

$this->db->insert('sometable', array('column1' => $item));
```

The insert function will escape `$item` automatically.

You can also do XSS cleaning of the post via `$item = $this->input->post('someitem', TRUE);`

*However you **should** escape your gets/posts if you are going directly into `query()`*

```
$item = $this->input->post('someitem');

$item_esc = $this->db->escape_str($item);

$this->db->query("INSERT INTO `sometable` (`column1`) VALUES ('{$item_esc}')");
```